# Is there any ERD table for Json format?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, json.net, react-native

I'm using JSON for my final year project. But i'm a bit confused how to draw an ERD table for JSON cause JSON is not a relational DATA model.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please extend your question with a code snippet of your work, so we can better assess the issue? Also, at the moment the question seems a bit too vague and generic to me. Could you describe the issue in more detail? Describe what you have tried so far, and why its not what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you can't really draw an ERM of JSON.  What you could draw, though, is a class diagram.

JSON is essentially built from three primitives:

- Object
- Array
- Value

The root of a JSON document is an Object.  And object can have many Values.  Each value can be a literal value, an Array or a child object.